# Does BQP contain any NP-Complete problem?

Tags: np-complete

From the Wikipedia [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP), "*the suspected relationship of BQP to other problem spaces*" diagram suggests no intersection between NP-complete problems and BQP.

Has this been demonstrated or not?

Comment: Proving or disproving $\mathsf{NP} \not\subset \mathsf{BQP}$ would be a huge breakthrough and wikipedia would know about it

Comment: Even weaker result is not known: Is GI $\in$ BQP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this is still open.

Comment: The grand authority utilizes the best of Kodlu's knowledge.